# How to extract bold text from pdf using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using a Apache pdfbox for extracting text. I can extract the text from pdf but I dont know how to know that whether the word is bold or not??? (code suggestion would be good!!!)
Here is the code for extracting plain text from pdf that is working fine.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument
    .load("/home/lipu/workspace/MRCPTester/test.pdf");
document.getClass();
if (document.isEncrypted()) {
    try {
        document.decrypt("");
    } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Document is encrypted with a password.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

// PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
// stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
stripper.setStartPage(1);
stripper.setEndPage(2);
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
String st = stripper.getText(document);
```

Comment: Do you have an example PDF with bold text? The problem is that not all bold fonts are marked as bold, and further more there are different poor-man's-bold variants. Thus, the mode of recognizing bold fonts or characters can be document specific.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The result of `PDFTextStripper` is plain text. After extracting it, therefore, it is too late. But you can override certain methods of it and only let through text which is formatted according to your wishes.

In case of the `PDFTextStripper` you have to override

```
protected void processTextPosition( TextPosition text )
```

In your override you check whether the text in question fulfills your requirements (`TextPosition` contains much information on the text in question, not only the text itself), and if it does, forward the `TextPosition text` to the `super` implementation.

The main problem is, though, to recognize which text is **bold**.

Criteria for boldness may be the word *bold* in the font name, e.g. *Courier-BoldOblique* - you access the font of the text using `text.getFont()` and the *postscript name of the font* using the font's `getBaseFont()` method

```
String postscriptName = text.getFont().getBaseFont();
```

Criteria may also be from the font descriptor - you get the font descriptor of a font using the `getFontDescriptor` method, and a font descriptor has an optional font weight value

```
float fontWeight = text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight();
```

The value is defined as

> (Optional; PDF 1.5; should be used for Type 3 fonts in Tagged PDF documents) The weight (thickness) component of the fully-qualified font name or font specifier. The possible values shall be 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, or 900, where each number indicates a weight that is at least as dark as its predecessor. A value of 400 shall indicate a normal weight; **700 shall indicate bold.**
>
> The specific interpretation of these values varies from font to font.
>
> EXAMPLE 300 in one font may appear most similar to 500 in another.
>
> *(Table 122, Section 9.8.1, ISO 32000-1)*

There may be additional hints towards **bold**-ism to check, e.g. a big line width

```
double lineWidth = getGraphicsState().getLineWidth();
```

when the rendering mode draws an outline, too:

```
int renderingMode = getGraphicsState().getTextState().getRenderingMode();
```

You may have to try with your the documents you have at hand which criteria suffice.

Comment: But when you detect that a TextPosition is bold how you can manage that (for example wrap the text with <b></b>?
Are you completely overriding processTextPosition without calling supper?

Comment: @lujop When I wrote that answer `processTextPosition` was the only method one could appropriately override, transporting the result to the output was difficult. Meanwhile (both in 1.8.11 and in 2.0.x) also `writeString` became a usable method to override, and as that method is nearer to the eventual output, it can be used to inject tags for bold etc., cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40039407/1729265). But keep in mind that there are many ways to create bold text, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26642060/1729265). For a general solution you have to check all of them.