# PDFBOX, Reading a pdf line by line and extracting text properties

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox to extract text from pdf files. I read the pdf document as follows

```
    PDFParser parser = null;
    String text = "";
    PDFTextStripper stripper = null;
    PDDocument pdoc = null;
    COSDocument cdoc = null;
    File file = new File("path");

    try {
        parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        parser.parse();
        cdoc = parser.getDocument();
        stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdoc = new PDDocument(cdoc);
        stripper.setStartPage(1);
        stripper.setEndPage(2);
        text = stripper.getText(pdoc);
        System.out.println(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But what I want to do is read the document line by line and to extract the text properties such as bold,italic, from each line.
How can I achieve this with pdfbox library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> extract the text properties such as bold,italic, from each line. How can I achieve this with pdfbox library

*Properties such as bold and italic* are not first-class properties in a PDF.

**Bold** or *italic* writing in PDFs is achieved either using

- different fonts (which is the better way); in this case one can try to determine whether or not the fonts are bold or italic by

  - looking at the font name: it may contain a substring "bold", "italic", "oblique"...
  - looking at some *optional* properties of the font, e.g. font weight...
  - inspecting embedded font file.

  Neither of these methods is fool-proof; or
- using the same font as for non-bold, non-italic text but using special techniques to make them appear bold or italic (aka poor man's bold), e.g.

  - not only filling the glyph contours but also drawing a thicker line along it for a bold impression,
  - drawing the glyph twice, the second time slightly displaced, also for a bold impression,
  - using a text or transformation matrix to slant the letters for an italic impression.

By overriding the `PDFTextStripper` methods with such tests accordingly, you may achieve a fairly good guess rate for styles during PDF text extraction.

Comment: Forget about bold,italic, from each line for a sec, how to read line by line then?

Comment: The `PDFTextStripper` the OP uses extracts the page content with system line separators between recognized lines. You can `split` at them.