# Extracting font size and boldness from PDF with PDF2Dom

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

[PDF2Dom](https://github.com/radkovo/Pdf2Dom) (based on the PDFBox library) is capable of converting PDFs to HTML format preserving such characteristics like font size, boldness etc. Example of this conversation is shown below:

```
private void generateHTMLFromPDF(String filename) {
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
Writer output = new PrintWriter("src/output/pdf.html", "utf-8");
new PDFDomTree().writeText(pdf, output);

output.close();}
```

I'm trying to parse an existing PDF and extract these characteristics on a line for line basis and I wonder if there are any existing methods within the PDF2Dom/PDFBox parse these right from the PDF?

Another method would be to just use the HTML output and proceed from there but it seems like an unnecessary detour.

Comment: You have accidentally tagged your question with `itext`, a competitor of `pdfbox`. I will now proceed to remove that tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDFBOX, Reading a pdf line by line and extracting text properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571317/pdfbox-reading-a-pdf-line-by-line-and-extracting-text-properties)