# How to get whether Character is bold or not in pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox API 2.0.1 version for reading PDF files. I want to extract the text properties and written the following code to get the bold property of text

```
@Override
protected void processTextPositon(TextPosition text)
{
    System.out.println(text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontWeight());
}
```

From the above code, I am getting 0.0 for every character even-though the character is in bold.
Please suggest solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The font weight is an optional entry, in your case it most likely is not there. You might want to look at [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19777953/1729265).

Comment: current version is 2.0.4 (won't change anything re your question)

Answer (score 2):

using`FontDescriptor.getFontWeight()`There is no guarantee of determining that whether the text is of bold or not.

I prefer you to use `text.getFont().getBaseFont().Contains("bold")` for extracting Bold text .

Comment: 'getBaseFont()' method is not available in pdfbox- 2.0.1 version

Comment: use `text.getFont().getName().toLower().Contains("bold")`.

Comment: I have used the method of testing the font name with some success, but I am looking at PDF where the font name is being returned as "Microsoft San Serif" regardless of whether the font is bold or not.  And getFontWeight returns 0 on both bold and normal strings.